# Is writing to a socket an arbitrary limitation of the sendfile() syscall?

Tags: unix, kernel, implementation, system-calls, sendfile

**Prelude**

`sendfile()` is an extremely useful syscall for two reasons:

First, it's *less code* than a `read()`/`write()` (or `recv()`/`send()` if you prefer that jive) loop.
Second, it's *faster* (less syscalls, implementation may copy between devices *without* buffer, etc...) than the aforementioned methods.

Less code.  More efficient.  Awesome.

In UNIX, everything is (mostly) a file.  This is the ugly territory from the collision of platonic theory and real-world practice.  I understand that sockets are fundamentally different than files residing on some device.  I haven't dug through the sources of Linux/*BSD/Darwin/whatever OS implements `sendfile()` to know why this specific syscall is restricted to writing to sockets (specifically, streaming sockets).

I just want to know...

**Question**

What is limiting `sendfile()` from allowing the destination file descriptor to be something besides a socket (like a disk file, or a pipe)?

Comment: In 2.6.33 and later the out_fd argument for sendfile can be any fd (not just a socket).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, the only thing limiting it is that "no-one's written the code yet".

However, I gather that the reason that no-ones written the code for those two cases you mention is that they both would require the data to be copied, which removes much of the advantage of using `sendfile` in the first place.

- For a file-to-file `sendfile`, you'd need a copy because otherwise the same page would have to be in the pagecache as both a clean page in the source file and a dirty page in the destination file.  I don't think the pagecache is built to handle that case at the moment (though of course, this could be changed if there was sufficient motivation).
- For a file-to-pipe `sendfile`, you need a copy regardless because the destination process needs to get a private, writeable copy of the data.  Anyway, for most uses of this case we already have `mmap`.

Answer (score 4):

I seem to remember that it was a limitation introduced in early Linux 2.6 (2.4 didn't have the limitation).

Since 2.6.17 Linux has the splice() system call which is similar; more flexible, but slightly less efficient. Linus talked about re-implementing sendfile in terms of splice(). See  http://kerneltrap.org/node/6505